# How can I replicate a premium file shares storage account across different regions?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I have a premium file shares storage account in the north-europe region and I would want to have a replica of it in the west-europe region to use in a DR scenario. A replication of type `GRS` or `GZRS` would have been the solution for this problem but unfortunately it is not supported for this type of storage account. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can make use of Azure file sync https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/file-sync/file-sync-planning to  replicate your storage account to another region for DR and another option is to use azcopy sync to replicate the storage account to another region azsync copy link- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-sync

Comment: Azure File Sync is related to file shares on Windows VM's, not Azure Storage Account file shares.

Answer (score 1):

For a typical DR scenario you should configure Azure Backup for Premium Files. You can restore to storage accounts in other regions.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-files

For a more "enterprise" scenario, you may want to consider using Azure NetApp Files which provides more comprehensive replication accross regions.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-netapp-files/cross-region-replication-introduction